# Python 3 Please Insert disk into drive

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, windows-7-x64

I get this error when running a python 3 script

[Sample error box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lMuU.png)

(edit) sorry forgot to mention this is on windows 7 if that wasn't clear. Selenium chrome web driver. let me know if you want to know anything else.

I think it would be impractical to post the whole project. I will provide a link to the git repository [here.](https://github.com/ohmaj/MPE)

Please excuse the amateur coding I'm working on refining my conventions.

This is a tool for scraping various sources, in this case website, for data. Specifically this is happening to the Kawasaki scrape. It happens once or twice in the course of scrapping aprox. 4500 parts. Normally i could handle this error well enough but I don't know how to handle the actual window it is currently requiring a physical click so if I leave this to run overnight it gets stuck there and wont finish.

the flow of the program in github is that i run the [part scraper file](https://github.com/ohmaj/MPE/blob/master/PartScraper.py) that is in the main directory that instantiates [user interface.](https://github.com/ohmaj/MPE/blob/master/Classes/User_Interface.py) then the file [run_all](https://github.com/ohmaj/MPE/blob/master/Classes/Run_All.py) then [distributor_kawasaki](https://github.com/ohmaj/MPE/blob/master/Classes/Distributor_Kawasaki.py) specifically in this case which inherits from [distributor](https://github.com/ohmaj/MPE/blob/master/Classes/Distributor.py).

(edit)Well [ariens](https://github.com/ohmaj/MPE/blob/master/Classes/Distributor_Ariens.py) did it too now.

I have scoured all the solution all over stack exchange and the internet and general and none of the solutions have worked.

(edit)I have tried uninstall just about everything i can from device manager to see if its a windows problem. I have reinstalled libraries. i have made sure everything is up to date.

The really strange part is that it only happens when i run the script file as normal, but not in pycharm. pycharm IDE has no problems with this at all.

for solutions I would obviously prefer to fix this issue.

If this question is lacking in some way please let me know before flagging it and i will fix/add anything that is needed. like i said I'm pretty new and am working on it I swear.

small aside if anyone has any pointers for me in general after looking at the code i would love to take any constructive criticism seperatly.

Comment: (edit) how does it show no research effort; is unclear or not useful?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes upon this problem as well, I figured out that the computer was running out of memory. I assume because of the browsing history. I don't know the best fix for this, but mine was to close, reopen the browser and then continue every so often to clear the memory. I am still playing around with the magical number for me but it will depend on the computers available memory.